# gedit:3457 Error: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'

Tags: updates, programming

I have an error with my first application which I don't understand :

```
(gedit:3457): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1971:11: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.  (gedit:3457): Gtk-WARNING **: 
Failed to parse /usr/share/themes/mac-os-lion-theme-v2/gtk-3.0/settings.ini:
```

Comment: can you clarify what are you trying to do and where did you find this error

Answer (score 0):

**Graphical sudo**

> You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications as
>   Root. You should use gksudo (kdesudo on Kubuntu) to run such programs.
>   gksudo sets HOME=~root, and copies .Xauthority to a tmp directory.
>   This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by Root.

you must use this way

```
gksudo gedit /path-to-file
```